# Как разбить диапазон дат на кварталы?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть диапазон дат:

```
create table t1 (df,dl) as  
    select date'2020-02-03' df, date'2020-07-24' dl from dual
```

Как разбить диапазон дат на кварталы так, чтобы границы диапазона являлись началом первого и последнего кварталов соответственно?

Ожидаемый результат:

```
  df         | dl
  -----------------------
  03.02.2020 | 31.03.2020
  01.04.2020 | 30.06.2020
  01.07.2020 | 27.07.2020
```

Comment: Рекурсивный CTE, TRUNC() до квартала ('Q').

Comment: Посмотрите вот это решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558492/oracle-break-dates-into-quarters

Answer (score 1):

Решение составлено из нескольких подсказок в комментариях:

```
with t1 as (
  select date'2020-02-03' df, date'2020-07-24' dl from dual )
select  
  case when level = 1
    then t1.df
    else add_months( trunc(t1.df, 'Q'), 3*(level - 1) )
  end df,  
  case when add_months( trunc(t1.df, 'Q'), 3*(level) ) - 1 > t1.dl
    then t1.dl
    else add_months( trunc(t1.df, 'Q'), 3*(level) ) - 1
  end dl
from t1
connect by add_months( trunc(t1.df, 'Q'), 3*(level-1) ) - 1 <= t1.dl;
```

Comment: А зачем вы отметили вопрос меткой [plsql]? Ни в вопросе, ни в ответе нет ни одной строчки кода на pl/sql.

Comment: @0xdb Извините. Погорячился... :)

Comment: Ничего страшного. Метка просто показывает контекст, в котором вы работаете, и вы могли получить ответ, который вас бы скорее вссего не устроил.